# How to login with Facebook using ReactJs, NodeJs, and JWT token?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, facebook

I found this tutorial https://medium.com/recraftrelic/login-with-facebook-and-google-in-reactjs-990d818d5dab that shows me how to login with Facebook using ReactJs. However, I'm trying to figure out how to implement the NodeJs backend using JWT token for the session handling. Can someone please help me understand how to implement the backend? I want to figure out how to authenticate the user? I'm using mysql for the database.

Here's how I've done this for logging in with email. I can't figure out how to do this with facebook.

```
app.use (
    session ({
        key: "userId",
        secret: "dddd",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            expires: 60 * 60 * 24,
        }
    })
);

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
User.login(email, password).then(result => {
   const id = result[0].id
   const token = jwt.sign({id}, JWT_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: 300,
   })
})
```

// to check if a user is authenticated
// use this as middleware

```
 const verifyJWT = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers["x-access-token"];
    if (!token) {
        res.json({
            status: "error",
            error: "You are not logged in"
        });
    } else {
        jwt.verify(token, "dddd", (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.json({
                    status: "error",
                    error: "You are failed to authenticate."
                });
                res.end();
            } else {
                req.userId = decoded.id;
                next();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: You need to share what you have tried on the node side including what libraries you are using, how you’ve configured the middleware, how you’ve configured the session storage and what errors/issues you’re seeing trying to implement that.

Comment: See Question. I added more details @AlexanderStaroselsky

Comment: Okay sure, but the token that is created by the react app using oauth login of Facebook won’t have the same issuer or secret as what you are validating against. You need to validate that the token is a valid token created by Facebook. Realistically if you are going to manage additional metadata of the user in the api, a service like auth0 can help to generate the tokens and provide mechanisms to validate tokens on both the front end and back end with libraries like passport-jwt and similar. For a simpler solution you can use https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-facebook/

Comment: so you are saying instead of using jwt, use passport for authentication @AlexanderStaroselsky

Comment: Passport is designed to provide a variety of different strategies that work with express and session management allowing you to authenticate, validate, serialize and deserialize users. You can just check jwt but you won’t really be able to check it like your trying because if you’re using oauth, you’re not the one actually making the token, at least how it’s generated in the article. Also if you front end and back end are on different domains, session won’t really be a thing.